# Multiple page versions and caching for anonymous users

Tags: caching

Is there a standard, or well accepted, method for allowing page caching when you have multiple versions of page, that don't involve using [Page Manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)?

For example, if you render out different versions of a page based on IP address, User-Agent, etc., page caching renders the code-based decisions useless, so some users may see the wrong pages.

The only method that I know about involves adding code to settings.php to alter `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to make the code-based decision and then to tack on extra variables, but gets messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the simplest way. The other option is to modify the key used in the cache. There is a 6.x memcache patch that I've been using http://drupal.org/node/942914

The latest version of http://drupal.org/project/authcache might be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the leads.  Do you know if there is a hook when you can still mess with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?  I haven't been able to fully unravel this yet.

Comment: It needs to happen before hook_boot so there is no "hook" that can be used. Easiest is to include a file in settings.php that will modify $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. If this is not an option patching your cache backend file is the other option. I've used both methods. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] works best for simple things like other $_SERVER variables. patching the cache backend works best for things like IP Geo location.